# PCA : Can I reverse the axis of the first principal component in R?

Tags: r, pca, cross-validation, ggbiplot

Here is a reproducible example :

```
set.seed(10)
pick <- sample(nrow(iris),nrow(iris)/2)
iris.training <- iris[pick,] 
iris.testing <- iris[-pick,]
pca.training <- prcomp(iris.training[-5])
pca.testing <- prcomp(iris.testing[-5])
autoplot(pca.training,loadings.label=T,loadings=T)
autoplot(pca.testing,loadings.label=T,loadings=T)
```

Which produces the following output : [image: biplot_pca_training] [image: biplot_pca_testing]

As one can see, pca on data.training and on data.testing produces very similar biplots but the first principal components has reversed its sign, they are mirrored. Is it possible to force a 180 degree rotation on the two components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the rotated variables. Changed code is as below. Notice retx=TRUE

```
set.seed(10)
pick <- sample(nrow(iris),nrow(iris)/2)
iris.training <- iris[pick,] 
iris.testing <- iris[-pick,]
pca.training <- prcomp(iris.training[-5], retx=TRUE)
pca.testing <- prcomp(iris.testing[-5], retx=TRUE)
autoplot(pca.training,loadings.label=TRUE,loadings=TRUE)
autoplot(pca.testing,loadings.label=TRUE,loadings=TRUE)
```

It produced the following outputs for training and testing.
[image: Training PCA plot]
[image: Testing PCA plot]

Comment: `retx=TRUE` is the default, see `?prcomp`.  Not sure why your PC1 axes are different from mine and the OP's, but the help page does warn that's a possibility.

Comment: @user2554330 You are right. Now it makes me think as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `autoplot` is the function from the `ggfortify` package.  There are probably two ways to do this.  The easiest is to just ask to reverse the x axis, by writing

```
autoplot(pca.testing,loadings.label=TRUE,loadings=TRUE) + scale_x_reverse()
```

[image: screenshot]

Notice that this didn't change any values:  the X axis now runs from positive to negative instead of the usual direction.

The second is to modify the `pca.testing` object to swap the signs on the x axis.
This is statistically valid:  PCA doesn't determine the signs of any components, but it's a bit tricky, because the signs show up in two places:  component `x` for the data points, and component `rotation` for the arrows:

```
pca.testing$x[,1] <- - pca.testing$x[,1]
pca.testing$rotation[,1] <- -pca.testing$rotation[,1]
autoplot(pca.testing,loadings.label=TRUE,loadings=TRUE)
```

[image: screenshot]

Not related to your question, but some advice:  don't use `T`, use `TRUE`, otherwise the next time you have temperature data, you may inadvertantly change the value, and cause havoc with your analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated.